# NoClassDefFoundError in HelloWorld program

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to run my first java class but I always get this error from the command java HelloWorld

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorld (wrong nam
e: helloworld/HelloWorld)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

I tried also with those commands and same error:

```
java -cp . HelloWorld

java -classpath . HelloWorld
```

Could you help me please solve my problem? Thanks

my code:

```
package helloworld;

/**
 *
 * @author Szymon
 */
public class HelloWorld {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the file called? You need to provide the [FQCN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name) - `helloword.HelloWorld` in your case.

Comment: Hmmm a packaging issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use fully qualified class name:

```
java -cp . helloworld.HelloWorld
```

Also, your current directory (or whatever the directory you specify with `-cp`) must be one level *above* the directory with `HelloWorld.class`.